# _tk_posted_on() - whole date instead of year

Tags: wordpress, function, datetime

I've got a problem with _tk_posted_on() function in ThemeKraft simple theme (Wordpress).
I'm begginer i would say, but i need help with piece of code :

```
function _tk_posted_on() {
$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() )
);

    $time_string = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">%3$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        $time_string
    );

    if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ){
        $time_string_update = '<time class="updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        $time_string_update = sprintf( $time_string_update,
            esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
        );
        $time_string_update = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            $time_string_update
        );
        $time_string .= __(', updated on ', '_tk') . $time_string_update;
    }

printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">Posted on %1$s</span>', '_tk' ),
    $time_string,
    sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', '_tk' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_author() )
    )
);}
```

It posts whole date and who published the post, i want it to only post the year.. I've tried edit it.. But i can't solve it..
Thanks for help :)

Comment: I know nothing about wordpress, but you could try this. I think that in `esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) )`, c is the specifier for how to show the date. Does your time look like this ( 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00) ?  I think that you are looking for the specifier `Y`. Just replacing the `c` with `Y` might solve the problem. This website gives you information about what different formats there are. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) . PS. I didn't dare post this as an answer, because I am a 100% wordpress noob (not even beginner). If it works out, I'll put this in an answer.

Comment: I solved it myself, thanks for the help tho..

Comment: Good to hear. Could you please post the solution as an answer so someone else that has the same problem can also learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function _tk_posted_on() {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date(Y) )
    );

    $time_string = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">%3$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        $time_string
    );

    printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">%1$s</span>', '_tk' ),
        $time_string,
        sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', '_tk' ), get_the_author() ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_author() )
        )
    );
}
```

There u go, this function displays only Year ^^